# Loop through table and find span class + checkbox checked for confirm box popup.

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am trying to loop through my table and find span with a class and a checkbox to see if its checked. Depending if its checked and that span class is there a confirm box will pop up. I keep getting Objects required or objects null type of errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Partial table code:

```
<td>
    <cfif stuff>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <cfelse>
        stuff
    </cfif>
        hidden field
    <cfif stuff>
        <span class="isOutForAudit">
            hidden field
        </span> 
    </cfif>
</td>
```

Javascript loop:

```
var table = document.getElementById("TableName");

    for (var i=0; i < table.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        if (row.getElementsByClassName("isOutForAudit") != null && row.getElementById("checkbox").checked == true)  
        {           
            if (confirm("Stuff") == true) 
            {
                document.myform3.action = Stuff;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using jQuery, or some other JS library to handle this for you? You could have this done in one line of code - and have it be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @ScottStroz Is there a way with jQuery to put in a confirm box without using a plugin? This all has to do with work. That is why I was using Javascript.

Comment: jQury is written in JavaScript, therefore, anything you can do in JavaScript, you can do with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Each checkbox has the class magicC. The span IDs correspond to to the checkbox values.

It loops through all the checkboxes, using the class name, searches for the span, and does an alert

```
<table><tr><td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="0" class="magicC">
   <span id="Audit_0">hidden field</span>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1" class="magicC">
       no hidden span
        </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2" class="magicC">
   <span id="Audit_2">hidden field</span>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" onclick="javascript:VChk();" valu="validate" /></td></tr>
    </table>

<script>
function VChk() {
    var chks = document.getElementsByClassName('magicC');
    for (i=0;i<chks.length;i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
        if(document.getElementById('Audit_' + chks[i].value) !== null) {
            alert('span ' + i + ' exists');
        }
        }
    }
}</script>
```

Demonstration fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1z29yxh9/ with only slightly different function declaration.

So you can work your cf code like this

```
<td>
    <cfif stuff>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="#numericID#" id="checkbox" class="magicC">
    <cfelse>
        stuff
    </cfif>
        hidden field
    <cfif stuff>
        <span class="isOutForAudit" id="Audit_#numericID#">
            hidden field
        </span> 
    </cfif>
</td>
```

The IDs don't have to be numeric, but they do need to be unique and id friendly (single words, alphanumeric characters, _, etc). For this reason, numeric IDs work best.

---

Edit: As Scott points out, you can do this with jQuery. The code in this case isn't much shorter jQuery frequently saves a lot of code AND, as he points out, makes cross-compatibility very much easier.

Here's a fiddle showing all three methods, you can use any of the three. (JS, JQuery-button bound, or JQuery form-submit-bound)

http://jsfiddle.net/540heL5v/1/

To use JQuery, you will either need to download and host the library, or let someone like Google do it. (Google willingly does this.). It's better for user bandwidth to reference a central, reliable host, like google (since they will likely already have the file downloaded, rather than needing to to download another copy from your site).

The code to call it is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

I did deliberatelly leave out `http/s:`. By not clarifying either, it pulls from the protocol of the requested page. Calling it from `https://hostsite.com` will make a secure connection for the call, where calling it from `http://hostsite.com` will call it normally.

Comment: Thanks :). I will have to give these a try.